# Visual Studio 2010 Thinks it's in Debug Mode (but it's set to Release mode)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, release, visual-studio-debugging

I have verified in the project properties and solution properties, configuration manager, that my solution and project are set to x64 Release. The output path is "bin\x64\Release\".

I have the following in app.xaml.cs (it's a C# WPF application), which was working shortly ago:

```
#if (!DEBUG)
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
#endif
```

Currently, in Release mode, the middle line is grayed out. Removing the "!" restores it.

When running, in Release mode, the mouse cursor is not hidden, and this section is seeminly skipped over.

Visual Studio, in another project, works well and fine with Debug vs. Release modes. Has anyone seen this behaviour, and does anyone have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the project setup in Release Mode or Debug mode in VS IDE what do you have your Solutions Configuration setup as..?

Comment: Have to tried "clean all", exit MSVS, then rebuild?  MSVS sometimes "remembers stuff" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Debug" and "Release" mode are just two different configurations that are created by default by Visual Studio.  There are a number of settings for each configuration set when they are created, but all of them can be changed manually.  You can change whether or not the compiler will compile the project with debugging information, whether optimizations are enabled, and *whether or not the DEBUG precompiler directive is defined*.  It would seem that the debug derictive was defined on your Release build.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.Now it seems such a silly mishap -- leaving Define DEBUG constant on.. defines DEBUG.

Answer (score 2):

Check your constant definitions, DEBUG can be turned on even for release configuration

Right click on the project, select properties, on the Build sheet in the general section make sure the "Define DEBUG constant" box is not checked.